# How to allow a user to select data through a view but not restrict access to underlying table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two databases DB1 and DB2
DB1 has a source table named 'Source'
I have created a login 'Test_user' in DB2 with Public access.
I have also created a view named 'Test_view' in DB2 which references data from DB1.dbo.Source

How can I do the following:
AS A Test_user

> SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.Test_view --Should work
>
> SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.Source --Should Not work

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your posting. Can you confirm you want to deny access to `DB1.Source` but yet still allow it to be indirectly accessed via `DB2.Test_view`?

Comment: Do you know what GRANT is?

Comment: Yes..I want to deny access to db1. Source but still allow to be accessed through db2. View

Comment: I created a login 'test_login'
I created a user 'test_user' for the login 'test_login'
I created a role named 'test' and added 'test_user' to that role.
I granted select and execute to the role 'test' on the view.

BUT still the following is not working

SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.Test_view --Not working --This should work

SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.Source --Should Not work --This is fine

Any help guys??

Answer (score 0):

We ended up as below:

```
USE db1
GO
-- Step 3
CREATE VIEW VW1
AS
SELECT *
FROM TBL1
-- Step 4
GRANT SELECT ON VW1 TO test_user

USE db2
GO
--Step 6
CREATE VIEW v2
AS
SELECT * FROM VW1
```